# Rails 3.0: No route error on PUT member route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3.0 application which features a simple voting mechanism that adds a count to a number of down votes.  I've set up a PUT route in routes.rb and created a method in my controller to handle it.  The down vote link itself renders properly, but on clicking it gives me a Routing Error No route matches "/venues/18/down_vote" error.

Here's my controller code:

```
def down_vote
  @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @venue.update_attribute(:mon_closed_accuracy_downvotes => @venue.mon_closed_accuracy_downvotes + 1)
      format.html { redirect_to(:back, :flash => { :success => "Shenanigans were successfully called on #{ @venue.name }'s closing time." }) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => 'show' }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @venue.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my route code for the down_vote route:

```
resources :venues do 
  put 'down_vote', :on => :member
end
```

View code (inside a partial for a list of venues):

```
<%= link_to 'Incorrect?', down_vote_venue_path(venue), :method => :put %>
```

Again, the view itself renders fine, and the link renders as expected:

```
<a href="/venues/15/down_vote" data-method="put" rel="nofollow">Incorrect?</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are right. I misread the API. Probably got the issue mixed up with something else. Sorry about that :)  Can you confirm in the app logs that the server is receiving a PUT request indeed?

Comment: No worries. :) Now that I'm looking at the logs it appears that its actually doing a GET request for some reason: Started GET "/venues/18/down_vote" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-28 01:01:41 -0500. Weird, figured it would do a put request since the data-method attribute was formed as expected.

Comment: I would still switch to using a button since links are expected to `GET` resources and can be right-clicked and opened in a new tab/window.

Comment: Good point; I switched to it a button, so now its this: <%Q button_to 'Incorrect?', :action => down_vote_venue_path(venue), :method => :put %> and now the page won't render and I get this: No route matches {:action=>"/venues/17/down_vote", :method=>:put, :controller=>"venues"}

Comment: Looks like my original code is now working, with the only change being that instead of calling `update_attribute` in the controller, it's calling a method in the venue model which increments the down vote in the model instance and does a plain `save!` call.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got a problem with your javascript. Are you including the proper files? What does your layout look like?

Comment: Aside from the Mapstraction and Google Maps API includes I added, this is what Rails included in the layout: <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1299653484" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1299653485" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1307343450" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Looks like my version of jQuery is 1.5 and the doesn't include the jquery_ujs.js file in your vote example:  https://github.com/BM5k/vote_sample/tree/master/public/javascripts, which uses 1.7.  The jquery-rails gem I installed seemed to put a bunch of stuff in rails.js to handle it.  I'll try updating the gem...

Comment: I used jquery-rails [1.0.18](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/546029a1bf45566f98b3d69abca852f593bf9f26)

It changes the list of scripts that are included by `=javascript_include_tag :defaults` so that jquery, jquery-ui (if used) and the jquery-ujs scripts are all loaded

As an aside, all of this is much easier in rails 3.1, where jQuery is the default.

Comment: Hrmm... specifying 1.0.18 for the gem version and running a Bundler update didn't seem to add ujs or change any of the js files in the project.  I guess I can try copying over the js files in vote_sample now that the right version of at least the gem is installed.  Failing that, might get brave and upgrade to Rails 3.1.

Comment: Looks like running `rails g jquery install` helped upgrade jQuery and installed the ujs file.  I also had to change config/application.rb to point the :defaults symbol to more than nil: `# config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)`.  Removed the manually jquery script tags and used a `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` to get it all in sync.  Left these steps in case someone from the future visits this page. Now to solve my original problem...